# Advantage of reading xpath from parent node in Selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I tried reading xpath for selenium from current node which works perfectly fine for Chrome and Firefox. But same xpath sometimes doesn't work on IE, Edge and Safari browser. If I tried identifying the same element from parent/grand-parent node those browsers easily recognizes it.
Also sometimes for same element only CSS selector works on Safari.
What could be reason for this? Does traversing from parent to child node gives ample time to those browsers to read the element?

Comment: RISHI KHANNA could please share the link you are using on multiple browsers?. Also, tell me which element you are looking at.

Comment: It's actually client project which requires user credentials to login. Unfortunately I am not in a position to share.